# Add suffix on duplicates in pandas dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests, duplicates

I am writing a script to download images. I'm reading a excel file as a pandas dataframe

- Column A - url links
- Column B - Name

Downloaded images will have this name, example "A.jpeg".

There will be duplicates in Column B [Name] in that case I would like to add a suffix on the image name.

So that the output will be

```
A.jpeg
A-1.Jpeg
..
```

Code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\exdata1.xlsx')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
 url = row['url']
 file_name = url.split('/')
r = requests.get(url)  

file_name=(row['name']+".jpeg") 

if r.status_code == 200:
 with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
  f.write(r.content)
  print (file_name)
```

I have been trying cumcount but can't really seem to get it to work..
Apreciate all the help I can get

Comment: Can you fix the code please : wrong indentation + antislahes.
What's the goal of antislashes ? escape the bracket characters ?

Comment: Hi sorry about that
Cleaned up the code now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\exdata1.xlsx")
cnt = {}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    name = row["name"]
    if name not in cnt:
        cnt[name] = 0
        name = f"{name}.jpeg"
    else:
        cnt[name] += 1
        name = f"{name}-{cnt[name]}.jpeg"

    url = row["url"]
    r = requests.get(url)
    
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(name, "wb") as f:
            f.write(r.content)
            print(name)
```

---

This will download the files as `A.jpeg`, `A-1.jpeg`, `A-2.jpeg`, ...

Comment: This was exactly what i needed, easy to read and understrand too!
Thank you for your support.